# Detecting HTML form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

I've got a generic form below that has a button and that button will post to a database, what the button does isn't really what this question is about, the question is about detecting an html form submit in angular.

```
<div class="example" ng-controller="ExampleController as app">
   <h1>Button below Form appears when fields full</h1>
   <form method="post" action="do_button_stuff"><TABLE BORDER="1">
     <TR><TD>Your name</TD>
     <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="name" SIZE="20"></TD></TR>
     <TR><TD>Your E-mail address</TD>
     <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="email" SIZE="25"></TD></TR>
   </TABLE></form>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-show="filled_form">
</div>
```

I'm a native PHP programmer and new to Angular and to Javascript, so I'm working on being a full stack dev. I have used jQuery before. But I'm out of my element and don't have a normal process flow as to how to get through this hurdle. I **suspect the solution is either Javascript or jQuery** or adding the right unknown angular **html-tags to the form DOM element**. The idea is to provide a sort of client side validation, so that a user couldn't be able to use the post button unless they at least attempted to fill out the fields. Of course I have server side validations as well.

Is it necessary to find an answer for this with Angular.js, or should I keep it simple and  use only javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add to your `<form>` `ng-submit="here_function_name(variables)"` and remember to move your button inside `<form></form>` tags.

After click on button, angular will execute `here_function_name(variables)` which should be defined in `$scope` in your controller. You can put your validation in this function.

To get access to values in your inputs, there is example below (using `ng-model`).

See example of `ng-submit` and forms in angular here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

Comment: Nono, not "After click on button" -- that implies you can see the button in order to push it. After input fields are populated, the button appears

Comment: Check this one too https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state There is disabled button before form is filled in good way

Comment: [The answer appears to be here on the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form)